# Excel Chart not Updating after Macro (Automatic is turned on)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a chart that does not updated after I run a macro to expand/collapse grouped rows.  If I expand and collapse them manually it works fine and the chart appears fine.

Automatic formulas is turned on.  The odd thing is, if I just delete a random row in the workbook, the chart refreshes and the values go back to what they should be instead of `#VALUE!`.  I tried adding this to my macro, but still nothing.

Here is what I have in my macro.  Also - Excel 2016.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function

Sub Expand_All()
  ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
End Sub

Sub collapse()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

or

```
Application.Calculate
```

at the end of your macro. It will force all the data in the worksheet/application to recalculate.